# Primary Decomposition Theorem question

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a proof of the Primary Decomposition Theorem, and I am stuck on a part of the proof. The questions are at the end; many thanks for your help.

Let $T:V→V$ be linear operator whose minimal polynomial factors into monic, irreducible, pairwise coprime polynomials: $m_T (t)=p_1 (t)\cdots p_k (t)$. Then:

1. $V$ decomposes as a direct sum of $W_i$, $V=W_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus W_k$
2. The $W_i$ are $T$-invariant
3. $p_i$ is the minimal polynomial of $W_i$

Proof of 1

We must show (i) $V=W_1+\cdots+W_k$ (ii) $W_1\cap\cdots\cap W_k$

(i) By assumption, the $p_i$ are coprime, therefore there are polynomials $q_i$ such that $p_1(t)q_1(t)+\cdots+p_k(t)q_k(t)=1$. We multiply this identity by $v$ and substitute $T$ for $t$; $v=p_1(T)q_1(T)v+\cdots+p_k(T)q_k(T)v$.

We take $w_1=p_1(T)q_1(T)v,\dots,w_k=p_k(T)q_k(T)v$, then $v=w_1+\cdots+w_k$ and $V=W_1+\cdots+W_k$.

Questions

1. Do we take $w_i=p_i(t)q_i(t)v$ as both $w_i$ and $p_i(t)q_i(t)v$ are vectors with any entries and they can therefore equal each other or is there some other reason?
2. In part 2 of the proof ($W_i$ are $T$-invariant) $W_i$ is taken as Ker $p_i(T)$, so I'm assuming that's why we substitute $T$ for $t$?

Comment: I fail to see why $w_i = p_i(T) q_i(T) v$ is in $\ker p_i(T).$

Comment: I also think you have a few fundamental misunderstandings. For one, it is not true that we "multiply this identity by $v$ and substitute $T$ for $t.$" In fact, the point is that if $p_1(t) q_1(t) + \cdots + p_k(t) q_k(t) = 1,$ then $p_1(T) q_1(T) + \cdots + p_k(T) q_k(T) = I,$ where $I$ is the identity operator. Consequently, the image of $v$ under $p_1(T) q_1(T) + \cdots + p_k(T) q_k(T)$ is simply $v$ for any vector $v$ in $V.$